# Yandex карты. Отображение

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Использую данный пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation , но не могу сделать так что бы карта появлялась на странице сразу (а не после нажатия на кнопку). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Создавайте карту (`map = new ymaps.Map(...)`) не в колбеке geocode, а просто при загрузке страницы. Как в примере с обычной картой https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/mapbasics

Comment: Можете показать пример как? Что бы не потерять подсказки (suggest)

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не получается? Создаёте карту, SuggestView, вызываете `geocode`, всё как в примере.

Comment: Использую данный пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation , но не могу сделать так что бы карта появлялась на странице сразу (а не после нажатия на кнопку). Пробовал туда сразу передавать координаты, но карта всё равно не отображается (скрин: https://prnt.sc/sbjizl )

Answer (score 1):

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10
    });
});
```